# Confused over using sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds

I have heard people say

> I was talking over phone during my visit to the doctor.

but is it idiomatic if I say

> I was talking over phone during my visiting to the doctor.

Answer (score 0):

I think that either of these would be idiomatic.

- I was talking on the phone during my visit to the doctor's office.
- I was talking on the phone during my visit to the hospital.

In other words the change from "doctor's office" to "hospital" makes no difference to the rest of the sentence.

I have some doubt about "during visiting." I think that "while" is a conjunction (usually) and "during" is a preposition. So we expect a second verb after "while" (talking while visiting the doctor, talking while driving home) and a noun after "during" (talking during the visit, talking during the drive home). I see that in one case you actually wrote "during my visiting," treating "visiting" as a noun by attaching the word "my." I guess that this just sounds strange to me. "Visit" is the noun and "my visiting" just seems distracting.

I do not believe that we say "visiting to someone." Rather we say "visiting someone."

And "talking over phone," and "visit to doctor," and "visit to hospital" all sound strange too. We would expect at least an article after each preposition: "over THE phone," "to THE doctor" and "to THE hospital."

Comment: Why not 'visiting' would not be appropiate

Comment: @chaims why visiting wouldnot be appropiate

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you provided is not grammatically correct.

The correct version is:
I was talking over the phone during my visit to the doctor.

You need an article nearly any time you use a singular noun that is not a proper noun. Therefore, article ‘the’ will be used before the noun ‘phone’.
We can’t use ‘visiting’ after the proposition ‘during’ because a preposition is not followed by a verb or a gerund.

Comment: Use of 'the' before phone is not necessary. This link contains a table with a heading 'Where 'the' is not used" https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/artikel.htm; and that should make it clear.

Comment: Good point. I know there are exceptions but in this sentence we need to use the article ‘the’.